# AdS/CFT Correspondence With Discrete Bulk Geometry

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, tensor-network

I am looking for an answer from AdS/CFT perspective in 2+1D.

- If there is a discrete bulk geometry rather than continuous, is it possible to have CFT on boundary with discrete symmetries?
- Can we have a consistent description of CFT with discrete symmetries ( discrete translation, rotation etc) on boundary as holographic dual of discrete bulk theory?
- In what limits we can approach discrete CFT ( if it exists) from continuous CFT or vice-versa?

Does anybody know about some better arguments?

Comment: CFT with discrete symmetries is usually meant as global symmetries. When you say discrete translations or rotation it does not make sense because a CFT, by definition, includes the whole Lorentz group.

Comment: An example of a CFT with discrete symmetry is the Ising model, which has a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ global symmetry.

Comment: Thats right, Conformal group contains both translation and rotation symmetry. But I am looking to what extent we can break them and still retain AdS CFT kind of behavior.

Comment: Ok, then maybe clarify the body/edit the title. Like I said, "CFT with discrete symmetries" does not generally denote what you are after.